# How can I extract values from "getCurrentPosition" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm used to c-style programming, I cannot come up with how can I extract values from getCurrentPosition (function?).

For the case of this code,

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  var latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
  document.write("Current pos : " + latitude + ", "+ longitude);
});
```

I'd like to change it to c-like code :

```js
var a, b;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  var latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
  a = latitude;
  b = longitude;
  document.write("Current pos : " + latitude + ", "+ longitude);
});
document.write("Result " + a + " , " + b);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: any special requirement?

Comment: No, I just want to get values (latitude, longitude) outside of getCurrentPosition() !

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is asynchrone, so you have to call

```
document.write("Result " + a + " , " + b)
```

inside the callback, try this:

```
<body>
  <script>
  var a, b;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  var latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
  a = latitude;
  b = longitude;
  document.write("Current pos : " + latitude + ", "+ longitude);
  document.write("Result " + a + " , " + b);
});


  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to get values a, b outside callback, Is it impossible?